# Optimisation of AutoFilterMode

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have written this piece of VBA and it does exactly what I want it to do. However most of the values repeat themselves numerous time, and I am wondering if the below could be transformed into a loop. Surely this can be optimised in some way, but I am struggling to see how, particularly if "AutoFilter" can only carry one single "Field". Any idea?

```
With Sheets(7)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="america"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(18, 2) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="asia"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(19, 2) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="europe"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(20, 2) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="africa"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(21, 2) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="america"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="red"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(18, 3) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="asia"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="green"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(19, 3) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="europe"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="yellow"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(20, 3) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="africa"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="dark red"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(21, 3) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="america"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(18, 5) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="asia"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(19, 5) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="europe"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(20, 5) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
        .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="africa"
        j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        Sheets(15).Cells(21, 5) = j

        .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Quick question before I speed this up for you - the 4th last line says                                                                                                                                                                             .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="africs"                                                                                                                                      Should this be                                                                                                 .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="africa"?

Comment: Seems to me you'd probably be better off with some COUNTIFS formulas in `Sheets(15)`.

Comment: You'd be better off using the [Code Review Site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to request a code review of otherwise working code.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, you are correct, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gonna be faster to use `Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` istead of `AutoFilter` just for counting number of rows with some criteria. You can replace this:

```
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*apple"
    .Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="america"
    j = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
    Sheets(15).Cells(18, 2) = j
```

With this:

```
Sheets(15).Cells(18, 2) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(7).Columns(1), "=*apple", Sheets(7).Columns(14), "america")
```

So, you can easly replace your code by:

```
With Sheets(7)
    Sheets(15).Cells(18, 2) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(14), "america")
    Sheets(15).Cells(19, 2) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(14), "asia")
    Sheets(15).Cells(20, 2) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(14), "europe")
    Sheets(15).Cells(21, 2) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(14), "africa")
    Sheets(15).Cells(18, 3) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(15), "america", .Columns(12), "red")
    Sheets(15).Cells(19, 3) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(15), "asia", .Columns(12), "green")
    Sheets(15).Cells(20, 3) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(15), "europe", .Columns(12), "yellow")
    Sheets(15).Cells(21, 3) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(15), "africa", .Columns(12), "dark red")
    Sheets(15).Cells(18, 5) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(17), "america")
    Sheets(15).Cells(19, 5) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(17), "asia")
    Sheets(15).Cells(20, 5) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(17), "europe")
    Sheets(15).Cells(21, 5) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "=*apple", .Columns(17), "africa")
End With
```

It's fine at this point, because creating a loop would be tricky, according to fact that your conditions are irregular. However, you can wrap it like this:

```
cols = Array(2, 3, 5)
contin = Array("america", "asia", "europe", "africa")
colour = Array("red", "green", "yellow", "dark red")

For Each k In cols
    For i = 0 To 3
        If k <> 3 Then Sheets(15).Cells(i + 18, k) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(7).Columns(1), "=*apple", Sheets(7).Columns(12 + k), contin(i))
        If k = 3 Then Sheets(15).Cells(i + 18, k) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(7).Columns(1), "=*apple", Sheets(7).Columns(12 + k), contin(i), Sheets(7).Columns(12), colour(i))
    Next i
Next k
```

Comment: Thanks a million Limak. The irregularity of the criteria made it difficult for me to come with a loop. COUNTIFS is a great idea.